# Getting error "invalidRequest" when creating upload session (Microsoft Graph Api)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the below error when creating upload session (Microsoft Graph Api).

{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6e9cc58e-d3b9-456e-a794-90486969296e",
            "date": "2020-04-06T20:53:18"
        }
    }
}

Post request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/testapi:/createUploadSession

Request body :

Comment: I am using Microsoft SDK for java, I am not able to figure out, how to send conflictBehavior with upload session. How did you pass?

Answer (score 3):

I have modified the request as below to make it work. See below :

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01WCLVX5B7JBMYFMQKWNA3NVFODWCDUPGB:/3.pdf:/createUploadSession

Comment: Also set the below properties :

Authorization = Bearer  + token
Content-Type = application/json 
Method = POST

JSON Body below :

conflictBehavior = Rename
name = 3.pdf(filename)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SDK for java, I am not able to figure out, how to send conflictBehavior with upload session. How did you pass?

Comment: Below is my code snippet ; Try setting up in JSON Data.  :  
   SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = 'https://'||ecMicroGraphurl||'/v1.0/drives/'||cDriveId||'/items/'||cItemId||':/'||Environment.Variables.InputFileName||':/createUploadSession';
   SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data TYPE = JSON.Array;
   CREATE FIELD OutputRoot.JSON.Data.Item IDENTITY (JSON.Object)Item;       
   SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.Item."@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" = 'replace';
   SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.Item.name = Environment.Variables.InputFileName;

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing C# from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=csharp) where the code was

```
var uploadSession = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
    .ItemWithPath(itemPath)
    .CreateUploadSession(uploadProps)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

In my case, I was able to fix it by updating `itemPath` by adding the full path to the file. For instance, if the path is

> /RootFolder/Folder1

just update with file name  like this

> /RootFolder/Folder1/MyFile.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API is a PITA. That said, this worked for me:

```
/drives/${driveId}/${childId}:/${filename}:/createUploadSession
```

If you are uploading to Sharepoint (instead of OneDrive), be sure to include only valid properties in the body payload (more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitemuploadableproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0)). This worked for me:

```
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "filename.txt"
            }
        }
```